# Java: Find if coordinate is on land or water

Tags: java, google-maps

Whats the easiest way to do this? I tried looking at the google maps api but the closest to this was elevation, which doesnt seem very accurate.

The duplicate link this has been marked as wasnt very helpful and didnt provide a concrete solution in java but ok.